# Does ApplicationHost.xdt work with Azure App Service Deployment Slots?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, kudu

Trying to apply IIS Rewrite rules on an App Service, working on the main slot, but failing on a secondary slot. Is this because it's a secondary slot, or because the file needs to go somewhere other than the site or wwwroot folder?

The actual error is that access is denied trying to set an allowed server header declared in the xdy

Comment: I have the exact same issue; the applicationHost.xdt file does not work on a seondary Web App slot. The configuration is the same, I've restarted the Web App but to no avail.

Comment: @The_Switch Years ago I had this same problem but IIRC there was no workaround, it just didn't work. But then it was a long time ago now.

Comment: @Frank, that's too bad.. I believe it might have something to do with the website identifier in the location element of the XML. But it's really trial / error at this point on.

Comment: @The_Switch Something is telling me that maybe putting the xdt in a subfolder...but it's like a dim spark from some ancient faded neurons

Answer (score 1):

Yes, applicationhost.xdt works with slots. So I'm guessing that whatever issue you are running into is not directly related to it being in a slot.

Please see [Understanding what could go wrong with xdt transforms](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Site-Extensions#understanding-what-could-go-wrong-with-xdt-transforms) for steps you can take to help identify the problem.